# Entity Framework Code First From Database Perform Migration to change attributes of a field specified as `bit` in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-migration

I am using Entity Code First from Data Base. 
This is my `user` model.

```
    public partial class User
    {
      //other fields
      [Required]
      [MaxLength(15)]
      public string Passkey { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public bool isAdmin { get; set; }  
    }
```

The code below was generated when I wanted to change the `Passkey` column in `Users` table from `varbinary` to `varchar`, which i did by changing the type from `byte` to `string` in the model as `public string Passkey { get; set; }` (this is the changed form). I was able to update the datatype.

```
public partial class AddPasskey : DbMigration
        {
            public override void Up()
            {
                AlterColumn("dbo.Users", "Passkey", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 15));
            }

            public override void Down()
            {
                AlterColumn("dbo.Users", "Passkey", c => c.Binary(nullable: false, maxLength: 15));
            }
        }
```

I have this 'isAdmin' property set as `required`. I want to remove this `required` validation, and set its default value to 0. I copied the code that was auto-generated for migration for `Passkey` and changed it. Below is the changed code, which is wrong.

```
    public partial class AddisAdmin : DbMigration
        {
            public override void Up()
            {
                AlterColumn("dbo.Users", "isAdmin", c => c.bool(nullable: false, defaultValue:0));
            }

            public override void Down()
            {
                AlterColumn("dbo.Users", "isAdmin", c => c.bool(nullable: false));
            }
        }
```

How do I perform this migration? What is the correct syntax for updating a field specified as `bit` in database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Enable-Migrations` first, this will generate a Migrations directory, you may have done this already.

After configuring your migration(s) you can then run then by running `Update-Database`.

I run the above commands from the "Package Manager Console", in Tools menu.

Also, to change the data type, you can also run SQL via the `Sql()` method:

`Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ALTER COLUMN isAdmin BIT")`

Comment: migrations are enabled as the update for `Passkey` column was possible. The error is with the syntax for updating the type for the `isAdmin` field.

Comment: You should be able to use Sql(), like so: `Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ALTER COLUMN isAdmin BIT")`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, define you model type as nulable using `bool?` syntax or `Nullable<bool>`. Anything that is not nullable in your code cannot be optional in the database. So, make it nullable and remove `[Required]` data annotation from your model above `isAdmin` property.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code you added manually and run the `add-migration` command again to add a new migration and a new file should be created with the change required, there you can alter it and set the default value to zero